# Confusion regarding --> in c++?

Tags: c++, decrement

I know that `-->` is not an operator. It is in fact two separate operators `--` and `>`.And it is same as like below opearation.

```
while( (x--) > 0 )
```

Now i ran two programs but it arose some confusion in me.
**First Program:**

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    while(----x>0)
   {
     cout<<x<<endl;
   }
}
```

**Output:** 8 6 4 2 
**Second Program:**

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    while(x---->0)
   {
     cout<<x<<endl;
   }
}
```

I got compilation error:

> lvalue required as decrement operand

Actually what is happening here?? why the first program is running successfully but not the second one??

Comment: [Near Dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30219293/179910).

Comment: No, my question is different. @Barmar

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that `--x` and `++x` are lvalues in C++ (they refer to the object `x`), but not in C.  `x--` and `x++` are not lvalues in either language.

Comment: I'll also note that `while(----x>0)` is much more clearly written as `while((x -= 2) > 0)` (though even that is a bit too terse for my own tastes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Result of `--x` is an lvalue, you can apply `--` to it again: `--(--x)`.

Result of `x--` is an rvalue, since `--` needs an lvalue, you can't do `(x--)--`.

Comment: And result of routinely writing code that looks like `----x>0` is looking for a new job ;)

Comment: Just a question, as its --x this reduces 1 from x right? Im not that good with C++ and found this question interesting.

Comment: Is there some exception to the rule about changing a value twice without a sequence point that stops `----x` from being undefined behavior?  Unlike most such situations, there is zero ambiguity about the sequence of operations.  But I don't recall the wording of the rule caring about the ambiguity.  I thought it just said doing this was undefined behavior.

Comment: @JSF: Since C++11, there are no sequence points, there are only ordered ("sequenced before") and unsequenced computations (and indeterminately sequenced, which is not an issue in this case).  I'll dig a bit deeper but I think one effect of the change was to make `--(--x)` not only syntactically and semantically correct, but also well-defined.

Comment: @JSF: The side-effect of `--x` (as `x-=1`) is sequenced before its value computation.  Since the value computation of `--` operand is sequenced before the value computation of the operator result itself, it means that in `--(--x)`, the side effect of `(--x)` happens first, then value computation of `(--x)`, then value computation of `--(--x)`.  Unfortunately I don't see a restriction on the sequence of the side effect of `--(--x)`.

Comment: why they have closed my question and marked as duplicate?? The question is not same as my question :(.

Comment: @setubasak: Yes it is.  Read the answers to the other one more closely.